# In magento 1.9 hosted paypal checkout not seeing cancel url

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.9, checkout

I set up paypal advanced hosted checkout layout C on magento website. When I customize and test the layout on paypal it shows the whole thing- a box for credit card and a Cancel link right below. But when I get to check out on the website- everything is there but the cancel link is not showing. I added CANCEL_URL before the link on paypal. Not helping. Any idea anyone?

Comment: Can you check to see if the cancel button exists in the html on the page, i have had a similar isue with sagepay modal popups where the cancel button was there, but it was off the page due to css issues.

Comment: Checked for that. Even deleted all css. Couldn't find the button there.